# How to block Mac OS X Interface while running a Terminal application (Exec)?

Tags: macos, interface, terminal

I’m working on Mac OS X and I wrote an UNIX Exec application (using c++ on CodeBlocks), which runs on Terminal. The application is very simple and consists in loops, and the user must provide answers to the given questions.

I’d like to know whether is it possible to block the entire Mac Interface while running the application on Terminal ? The idea is to run the application and force the user to stick totally to the application running, so he can’t quit it, run it again, and actually do anything else in the meanwhile, and so he is forced to follow the application to its very end in order to “unblock” the rest.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The Mac OS X I’m using is a Version 10.4.11.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a Mac running normally -- at least, I **hope** you can't.  But try searching for "kiosk mode" to see information about setting up a Mac to run a single application...it might give some ideas.